# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 error

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

I'm getting the error message in the title for the following code, the page is for adding sub categories to my forum.

```
<?php

include '../includes/connect.php';
include '../header.php';

echo '<h2>Create a Sub category</h2>';
if($_SESSION['signed_in'] == false | $_SESSION['user_level'] != 1 )
{
//the user is not an admin
echo 'Sorry, you do not have sufficient rights to access this page.';
}
else
{
//the user has admin rights
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
{
    //the form hasn't been posted yet, display it
    echo '<form method="post" action="">
        Category name: ';
        $sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_description FROM categories";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo '<select name="topic_cat">';
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row['cat_name'] . '</option>';
                }
            echo '</select><br />';


    echo 'Sub category name: <input type="text" name="sub_cat_name" /><br />
        Sub category description:<br /> <textarea name="sub_desc" /></textarea><br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Add Sub Category" />
     </form>';
}
else
{
    //the form has been posted, so save it
    $sql = "INSERT INTO subcategories(c_id, sub_cat_name, sub_desc)
       VALUES('" . $cat_id . ", " . $sub_cat_name . ", " . $sub_desc . "')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    echo 'The sub category <b>" . $sub_cat_name . "</b> has been added under the main category <b>" . $cat_name . "</b>';
    if(!$result)
    {
        //something went wrong, display the error
        echo 'Error' . mysql_error();
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'New Sub category succesfully added.';
    }
}
}
; ?>
```

My **categories** table is structured like so..

- cat_id
- cat_desc

My **subcategories** table is structured like so..

- id(AI)
- c_id
- sub_cat_name
- sub_desc

If I haven't provided enough information please let me know.

Comment: You haven't provided error message

Comment: Sorry, error message is in the title.
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not quoted things properly here:

```
VALUES('" . $cat_id . ", " . $sub_cat_name . ", " . $sub_desc . "')";
```

You need

```
VALUES('" . $cat_id . "', '" . $sub_cat_name . "', '" . $sub_desc . "')";
```

Note the extra single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You missed some quotes. Change

```
VALUES('" . $cat_id . ", " . $sub_cat_name . ", " . $sub_desc . "')";
```

to

```
VALUES('" . $cat_id . "', '" . $sub_cat_name . "', '" . $sub_desc . "')";
```

Comment: Thank you! that fixed it, now I need to figure out why it's inserting blank data into the database >_< thanks for your help with this issue.

Comment: You don't appear to be reading the $_POST variables into the variable you're putting in your query.